# apnserver gem not sending messages from ruby daemon

Tags: ruby, daemon, apple-push-notifications

i am using apnserver gem to push messages from my ruby daemon to apns, but messages are not being delivered, it shows no error. i tried sending from command line

```
apnsend --server gateway.push.apple.com --port 2195 --pem /home/fstech/anand/apps/demon/daemon_apns/tmp/apns-dev.pem \--hex-token 8ac76314c57640486952918f236cad321fb8cddcfa4394f191aafdf9b65cfa83\ --sound default \--alert Hello
```

this is the code i used, i used a message as "hello"

please help!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer.. it was sending messages to apple sandbox! changing the server to `gateway.push.apple.com` made it work :)